# Problem verifying PGP for Monero GUI wallet

Tags: security, hash-verification, gpg

I'm working in Windows and trying to verify the hash and binary of the Monero GUI wallet.

I followed the directions here: https://www.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/verification-windows-beginner.html#2-monero-signing-key

I got stuck at verifying the hash. I got the binary fate pgp key on github but didn't certify it. When I went to verify the PGP signed message of the hashes it told me "the data could not be verified" but the certificate looked like the key for binary fate was correct though.

Is this an error because the binaryfate key was not certified or something else? It seems unusual. I'm used to seeing a pop up saying that the signature is good but that the key is not trusted. This message just said the "data could not be verified" in Kleopatra or "key not valid" in GPA

Comment: I'm a happy command line cowboy in linux/mac and even windows (once my brain changes to MS gears).
But I found it a WHOLE lot easier/quicker to just compile from source/git pull than verify the pre-built binaries. But I do believe that the latest version has an (auto)update feature that takes all that mess way from you doing it and does it in the background.

Comment: @Number9 - Did you manage to resolve your issue?